# VBA if cell contains value then copy it

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, printing

Hi looking for a simple VBA
That would check column D from row10 to row 150 if cell contains value then copy that cell to D9 and do print activ sheet
If cell is empty do nothing

I get data from 1 to 150 and need to print label I'm currently doing one buy one copy paste and print
So if anyone could help I would appreciate it

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a code writing service. But putting something like "loop a range and copy data vba" in google should get you started nicely. And then, if you need more specific help with your code, you can ask it here.

Comment: Please, read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much in my first steps in VBA, and I had a similar case to this so I will try to help you out with something you can work with.

I did no understand what you meant by 'do print activ sheet' but I guess I will let you search for that part on your own, here is a bit that would get you started :

```
Sub CheckIfCellContainsValue()
 Dim index As Integer, NumberOfRows As Integer, ActualCellValue As Variant
  NumberOfRows = Range("D10:D150").Rows.Count
  For index = 10 To NumberOfRows + 9
    ActualCellValue = Range("D" & index).Value
    Debug.Print ActualCellValue
    If IsEmpty(ActualCellValue) Then
     ' Do nothing
    Else
     Range("D9").Value = ActualCellValue
     ' Insert your do print activ sheet code here.
    End If
    Set ActualCellValue = Nothing
  Next
End Sub
```

I know this looks complicated, and I welcome the community for any input to make my code less complex.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

### Copy If Not Blank (and Not Error Value)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PrintForNonBlankCells()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ' Instead of the previous line, I prefer something like:
    'Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim cCell As Range: Set cCell = ws.Range("D9") ' Criteria Cell
    
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = ws.Range("D10:D150") ' Lookup Range
    ' To make the previous line dynamic instead, you could e.g. do:
    'Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)
    'Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = ws.Range("D10:D" & LastRow)
    
    Dim lCell As Range ' Lookup Cell
    For Each lCell In lrg.Cells
        If Not IsError(lCell) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(lCell.Value) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                cCell.Value = lCell.Value
                ws.Calculate ' may not be necessary
                ws.PrintOut ' add the desired parameters (no parentheses)
            End If
        End If
    Next lCell

End Sub
```